# How to convert from map (bimap) into Graph

Tags: java, graph, maps, graph-coloring

I has just read this artices

```
http://www.ctl.ua.edu/math103/mapcolor/mapcolor.htm
```

and i don't understand, how can i convert this map (in bimap) into a Graph structure.
[image: Map in bitmap]

into
 [image]

If it's possible, can i implenment it with JAVA or other...

Comment: Shouldn't Italy be connected with Switzerland?

Comment: Maybe, i don't care the graph is Right or Wrong in this case:D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is apparently homework, shows no effort by the student, and does not ask about _specific_ problems in their _existing implementation_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `opencv` library to do this.

First use contour detection (by translating this `C++` code http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

Next you need to search for contours that have two points who are quite close to each other (search for the closest point pair and look if the distance is below some threshold). This can be done in `O(n log n)` per region pair.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you may use fringe around each state and then find the overlaps.
Sorry, I cannot upload images or use img tag for show it for you.